# AngularJS Tooltip Glossary

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would create a glossary, using an AngularJS directive. I start with this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/angularjsdc/KRVSQ/
I want to change the directive and substitute the modal with a tooltip.

```
app.directive('glossaryTerm', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'Glossary',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { /* empty */
        },
        template: /*HERE MY TOOLTIP TEMPLATE*/,
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function (scope) {
                    transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                        scope.term = clone[0].textContent.toLowerCase();
                    });
                },
                post: function (scope) {
                    // load the definition into scope
                    scope.getDefinition(scope.term);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestion? Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap ui tooltips: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qaBrk/
something is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Angular bootstrap ui example you had to:

include http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js

import the module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

and surround the variables you were passing into tooltip with `{{}}`

```
template: '<span><a class="glossary-term" href="#" tooltip="{{glossary[term]}}">{{term}}</a></span>',
```

Here's the modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DuSa/